# Resolve std::string to something else than ::std::string - is it possible?

Tags: c++, c++17, static-analysis, argument-dependent-lookup

**This is a follow-up question from:** [constructing string from NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304063/constructing-string-from-null?noredirect=1#comment102975855_58304063)

The following:

```
void test(const std::string& s);

int main(){
  test(NULL);
}
```

Fails when run, but is **legal** c++.

In order to try to catch some of those cases, as an alternative ive considering if  `std::string` can be *replaced* in the following way:

```
#include <string>


namespace {
namespace std {
    struct string : public ::std::string { //so far everything is good

    };
}
}


int main ()
 {
   std::string hello;//failure: ambiguous symbol

   return 0;
 }
```

Gives the following error:

```
<source>(17): error C2872: 'std': ambiguous symbol

C:/data/msvc/14.22.27905/include\string(19): note: could be 'std'

<source>(7): note: or       '`anonymous-namespace'::std'

<source>(17): error C2872: 'std': ambiguous symbol

C:/data/msvc/14.22.27905/include\string(19): note: could be 'std'

<source>(7): note: or       '`anonymous-namespace'::std'

Compiler returned: 2
```

I guess it is not possible to make it resolve without writing a more (fully) qualified name ? but is it possible to write std::string **in the global namespace** and have it resolve to something else while ::std::string *is* a valid type.

**Background**: after some failed attempts with cppcheck and cpp core check im trying to find all cases of `std::string str = 0` or `NULL` or `nullptr` - since those will fail at runtime. And I thought this might be a way forward.

**I ended up modifying the basic_string template ala. `basic_string(int) = delete;
    basic_string(::std::nullptr_t) = delete;` - this won't catch all cases but does indeed seem to catch  the direct cases at least**

Comment: I'd start with asking - why would you want to resolve `std::string` lookup to something else?

Comment: @bartop look at last part of question, background

Comment: I don't understand the background. Can you elaborate on what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @darune wouldn't just good 'ol regexp be enough to locate all these?

Comment: @MaxVollmer the idea is if I write the string class myself I can catch those cases at compile time

Comment: @bartop true, that might be possible - but i was kind of trying to avoid that (there will sometimes be some corner cases when 'regexing' that isn't correctly handled by regex)

Comment: Why would you want to "catch" that? What does that even mean? Why is `std::string str = 0` in your code in the first place? Why don't you fix these code errors instead of trying to write a custom type that tries to hide the errors? Sorry for the bunch of questions, but it seems you have a XY problem, and it would probably be better to explain in detail your situation and your goal. Don't show us your (attempt of a) solution, show us your problem.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Why so offensive ? :) this is more of static analysis question. This was a gotcha after some code changes. You can browse my recent questions and see where this is coming from. For example: cppcheck should be able to find this case easily but for some reason it's not finding it for me.

Comment: I apologize for failing to write my comment constructively. The questions are genuine and I wrote them in an effort to help you avoid making a strategic error in developing your software architecture.

Comment: Some additional thoughts: If you are scared that a regex won't find all cases of this problem in your code - how can you be sure you'll be able to inject this custom type in every place of the code where it'd needed to be? If you want to replace `std::string` with a custom type that silently ignores `nullptr` assignments, why don't you simply replace all occurences of `std::string` in your code base with `MyCustomNullPtrSafeString` instead of a custom type named `std::string`?

Comment: Also your question should be self-contained. If it's helpful to read other questions you posted, or other external information to fully understand the context of your situation, you might want to link to that external information and summarize it in your question.

Comment: The error is justified and should not be bypassed. You are hiding an already existing type so that is ambiguous. If you want to redefine the behaviour of `std::string`, don't override it like this but create your own string class outside of the `::std` namespace (or replace your anonymous namespace with a named namespace).

Answer (score 1):

> Resolve `std::string` to something else than `::std::string` - is it possible?
>   [...]
>   ...as an alternative ive considering if `std::string` can be replaced in the following way...

As far as I know, **it is not possible outside of your anonymous namespace scope** because you have no way to resolve the ambiguity (not to my knowledge).

As you can see below, since you are inside the scope of the anonymous namespace, it will be fine:

```
#include <string>

namespace
{
    namespace std
    {
        struct string : public ::std::string
        {

        };
    }
    std::string hello; // Fine
}


int main()
{
    std::string hello2; // Cannot be something else that ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

---

But even worse, the problem is not about `std::string` itself but about the `std` namespace.

Indeed, outside of the scope of your anonymous namespace, every call of `std` becomes ambiguous too.
This is the error pointed by the compiler. There are two `std` namespaces accessible as is from the global scope.

So the following example becomes broken:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace
{
    namespace std
    {
        struct string : public ::std::string
        {

        };
    }
    std::string hello; // Fine
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a; // FAIL: reference to 'std' is ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

To fix this ambiguity over accessing the original `std` namespace, you'll need to write it as follows:

```
::std::vector<int> a; // Fully qualified name: Only way to refer to the `::std` namespace
```

As you can see, it still does not solve the issue and even worse, it adds a huge inconvenience.

---

Therefore the morality is:

- Do not hide an already existing type but create a distinct one instead.
- In the same way, do not hide a namespace (by defining the same namespace into an anonymous one --> evil).

---

*(I'm open to any improvement proposal of this answer)*

Comment: You could import all the _content_ of `::std` into your own `std` namespace though, so that ambiguity is not insurmountable, just very inconvenient.

Comment: @MSalters But we will still encounter the first case error (where `string` was imported into he's own `std` namespace), isn't it ? Tell me if I've misunderstood something of your comment.

Comment: None of your examples actually **import** `::std::string`; instead they define another `string` that's inherited from `::std::string`. I.e. it's not `namespace { namespace std { using string = ::std::string; }}`. So I think you misunderstood my comment, yes.

Comment: @MSalters Ah ok, I now understand what you mean. But it does still not compile as is. Moreover, the OP want to redefine the `std::string`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that darune isn't trying to **redefine** `std::string`. I suspect you're not entirely familiar with the wording used in the C++ Standard? E.g. the "One Defintion Rule"? AFAICT, the goal is to affect the **name lookup** of `std::string`. Since this involves two names, there are two name lookups.

Comment: @MSalters By reading the background he specified, darune wants to handle the cases where `std::string` is initialized with `0`, `NULL` or `nullptr`. This is why he has defined a subclass that inherits `std::string` but with the same name. If it is not _"trying to **redefine**"_, I don't know what it is...

Comment: @Fareanor FYI i ended up modifying the actual `::std::basic_string` instead - that feels somewhat risky as does search and replace and back again on this scale. The question still stands though - but I guess you are right that the lookup cannot be hacked like that

Comment: @darune To be honest, it's a real puzzle. I tried to find a way around but I couldn't :) Regarding your initial issue, if you want to make it fail at compile-time, I can't find something better (something else ?) than the answer [VTT has proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304645). But I want to notice that you pointed a really good question.

Comment: **I ended up modifying the basic_string template ala. `    basic_string(int) = delete;
    basic_string(::std::nullptr_t) = delete;` - this won't catch all cases but does indeed seem to catch  the direct cases at least**

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this kind of solution : Rather than working on std::string, you work on the function that will cause the problem

```cpp
#include <string>

void test(const std::string& s){

}
// add a new function which use a pointer : 
void test (const char* _Nonnull s) {
    test(std::string(s));

}
int main()
{
    test(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Then clang will generate a warning : 
    1 warning generated.

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0

<source>:13:14: warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]

test(NULL);
```

see https://godbolt.org/z/PujFor

Comment: **I ended up modifying the basic_string template ala. `    basic_string(int) = delete;
    basic_string(::std::nullptr_t) = delete;` - this won't catch all cases but does indeed seem to catch  the direct cases at least**

Comment: _Nonnull isn't standard c++ afaik ?

Comment: @darune not it is clang specific : for gcc it is __attribute__((nonnull)) for Microsoft it is __assume. The standards c++11 and higher have the static_assert which perform compile time assertion checking.

Comment: @darune you can add your solution as answer to this question.

Comment: can you show an example with __assume - it's not working well for  me https://godbolt.org/z/beZhzc

Comment: @darune indeed, It seems that the microsoft compiler does not provide the same level of checking that gcc and clang (__assume does no check as I first though). According to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641514/when-do-i-use-attribute-nonnull-vs-not-nullt/38641960#38641960 the MSVC only uses assume as a hint. I did not find any way to do compile time checking : all I found was runtime check, which is not what you want